# Почему текст не идет в одну линию, если родительский элемент имеет display: flex

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, flexbox

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему текст не идет в одну линию, если родительский элемент имеет display: flex

Comment: Когда хотите разобраться в проблеме, нужно прикреплять код, чтобы пользователи могли прочитать ваш код, прочитать в чём проблема, и дам вам совет, а возможно ответ на ваш вопрос. А так сложно понять что вы написали и почему у вас не получилось.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
    .container {
        display: flex;
    }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <p>Июнь</p>
    <p>2022</p>
</div>
```

[image: скрин, все в одну строку]

Если остается проблема, прикрепите код к вопросу, может я не совсем вас понял